# Apply stored procedure to multipe items

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure, for example:

```
EXEC [dbo].[HowOldAmI] @date
```

I now have multiple dates (a list of @dates) that I want to run the stored proc on

Is there a manner to run a stored procedure on the results of a select statement?

Comment: What is the SPROC doing, in general?

Comment: Also, what **concrete** database is this for? SQL is just the query language - not the database - but things like stored procedure are highly **vendor-specific**, so please update your tags with the appropriate database product (MySQL? Postgres? IBM DB2? Ingres? SQL Server? Oracle?) that you're using - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedures are used to encapsulate some business logic but when you want to do some computations go for Functions as they can be used inline with select statements.So,  Re-write logic in stored procedure as a function as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION HowOldAmI (@date datetime)
RETURNS int AS  
BEGIN 
    -- logic goes here
END
```

and then the select query as:

```
SELECT * ,
     HowOldAmI (T1.[date])
 FROM
     [Table1] T1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a function instead of a procedure you can call it in your select statement. Otherwise you'll have to create a cursor and loop over your results.